# how to use python jsonpath_ng filter nested data

Tags: python, json

need to find dict in `[]` , according specific value , but cannot find.
which I hope return value is
`[{ "uid": {"type": "t2", "id": "world"}, "attrs": { "value": 456 } }]`

```
import json
from jsonpath_ng.ext import parse

json_str = '''[
{
  "uid": {"type": "t1", "id": "hello"},
  "attrs": {
    "value": 123
  }
},
{
  "uid": {"type": "t2", "id": "world"},
  "attrs": {
    "value": 456
  }
}
]
'''
json_obj = json.loads(json_str)
[match.value for match in parse('$.[*].attrs[?value > 200]').find(json_obj)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find how to use `jsonpath_ng.ext` to `parse'

```
[match.value for match in parse('$[?attrs.value > 200]').find(json_obj)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
import json
from jsonpath_ng import parse

json_str = '''
[
    {
        "uid": {"type": "t1", "id": "hello"},
        "attrs": {
            "value": 123
        }
    },
    {
        "uid": {"type": "t2", "id": "world"},
        "attrs": {
            "value": 456
        }
    }
]
'''

json_obj = json.loads(json_str)
expr = parse('$.[*]')
matches = [match.value for match in expr.find(json_obj) if match.value['attrs']['value'] > 200]
print(matches)
```

Output:

```
[{'uid': {'type': 't2', 'id': 'world'}, 'attrs': {'value': 456}}]
```

Comment: Thanks Mahboob, but why $.[*].attrs cannot filter, how to modify ext expression ?

Comment: @RelaxZeroC when I tried with the * I get this error 
jsonpath_ng.exceptions.JsonPathLexerError: Error on line 1, col 2: Unexpected character: ?
So I bypass it.